# make source and target to be sync in informatica

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-cloud

I have a scenario where

1st run: 500 records loaded to target from Source.

But for 2nd run you get 450 records from Source,

The target and source are to be sync for each run,

how do you sync i.e delete the extra 50 records in the target? in Informatica PC/IICS.

Answer (score 1):

Just truncate the target table at the start of the run

Comment: what if there are millions of records. it will take lot of time to truncate and load every time, right?.

Comment: Truncate is pretty quick (normally) - delete is probably slow. You could do a “Target minus Source” SQL statement in your source qualifier to get the records that only exist in the target and use that to drive the deletion

Answer (score 0):

Truncate would be the best option, if the delta between the source and target is  in millions. But in case if the delta record-set between source and target is small then you could add index on target and with the help of lookup, validate if the record is addition or deletion and perform the relevant action.